# Unable to execute spatial join after CRS transformation in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, spatial-join, geodataframe

I'm trying to join a points GeoPandas GeoDataFrame with a polygon GeoDataFrame, but I'm getting an empty results (inner join).

## The points GeoDataFrame

I'm loading it by using latitude and longitude. `epsg=4326`. If I execute a `points.explore()` it is shown correctly in the map.

```
Puerta del Sol A    POINT (40.41721 -3.70183)
Puerta del Sol B    POINT (40.41731 -3.70160)
Miguel Moya     POINT (40.42059 -3.70584)
```

[image]

## The polygon GeoDataFrame (districts)

This GeoDataFrame is loaded by reading a *.shp* file. automatically `epsg=25830` is loaded.

When printing this GeoDataFrame after changing CRS, it is inverted

```
districts_4326 = districts_25830.to_crs(df.crs)

CENTRO  POLYGON ((-3.69316 40.40735, -3.69320 40.40720...
LATINA  POLYGON ((-3.72261 40.41138, -3.72182 40.40851...
CARABANCHEL     POLYGON ((-3.71932 40.39984, -3.71901 40.39983...
USERA   POLYGON ((-3.68315 40.36474, -3.68314 40.36449...
```

However, even that the points of the polygons are inverted, if I execute a `districts_4326.explore()` regions are shown correctly.

[image]

## The join

The problem comes when I try a spatial join, I always get empty result:

```py
points.sjoin(districts_4326, how="inner", predicate = 'overlaps')
```

I have tried with all kinds of predicate, but still empty results.

I suppose that the problem is because the transformation of districts is returning inverted coordinates, but I don't understand why it's shown correctly in the map.

Any ideas?

Comment: try plotting both points and polygon in the same figure? cannot figure why coords would flip. Maybe you can share your data?

Comment: Have you tried with the `intersects` predicate?

Comment: @AmanBagrecha, you can find oboth code and datasets over here:
https://github.com/miguellobato84/geodata-maps

Comment: @Mintx, yes, I have tried all kind of predicates

Comment: Wouldn't -3.7 40.4 be correct for Madrid? Have you tried to load and project with a different software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Points` are flipped.

`Folium.Map` uses (Lat, Long) as arguments, but Shapely `Point` object uses (Long, Lat). That is the issue here.

From the doc string of Folium.Map

```
location: tuple or list, default None
    Latitude and Longitude of Map (Northing, Easting).
```

From the code you [shared](https://github.com/miguellobato84/geodata-maps/blob/main/Bicimad.ipynb), flip the "coordinates" as longitude, latitude and things should work fine. Also, use `intersection` predicate here.

```py
stations = [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": { "type": "Point", 
                       "coordinates": [float(station["latitude"]), float(station["longitude"])] }, # <---- here
          "properties": station
       } for station in raw["stations"]]
```

Comment: thanks! that works for me :D